# How to move the central widget in PyQt in python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow

Im using PyQt5 and I know you can make other things like buttons move to other positions with move() but that isn't working for me in this instance, however it is working when I set up the positions for some of the buttons I made earlier.

For some reason when I try to make my widget DrawImage go to a certain part of the window It never does and instead just stays in the top left corner.

This DrawImage is going to be inserted into another class I have that sets up the window DrawImage will be placed in. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

```
import PyQt5
import sys
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets  
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore


class Homework4(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Triangle Peg Game')
        self.setToolTip("Play the triangle peg game!")
        self.Left_button = LeftBtn(self)
        self.Right_button = RightBtn(self)
        self.Top_Button = TopBtn(self)
        self.Down_Button = DownBtn(self)

        #setting the background color
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.gray)
        #p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.gray)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        #Central Widget
        self.Draw = DrawImage(self)   #############
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Draw)

        self.show()



class LeftBtn(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setText("Left")
        self.resize(40,200)
        self.move(0,0)
        #self.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)    #bind the button to an event slot

class RightBtn(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setText("Right")
        self.resize(40,200)
        self.move(360,0)
        #self.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit) 

class TopBtn(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setText("Top")
        self.resize(320,20)
        self.move(40,0)
        #self.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit) 

class DownBtn(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setText("Down")
        self.resize(320,20)
        self.move(40,180)
        #self.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
```

This is my DrawImage class:

```
class DrawImage(QtWidgets.QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.move(200,50)
        self.setFizedSize(100,100)  

    def paintEvent(self, event):              #use to draw on the canvas
        paint = QtGui.QPainter()
        paint.begin(self)

        paint.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        # make a white drawing background
        paint.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        paint.drawRect(event.rect())
        # for circle make the ellipse radii match
        radx = 10
        rady = 10
        # draw red circles
        paint.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        for k in range(12, 22, 1):    # 125, 220, 10
            center = QtCore.QPoint(k, k)
            # optionally fill each circle yellow
            paint.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)
            paint.drawEllipse(center, radx, rady)
        paint.end()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Homework4()     #create an object of Homework4, which contains the main window
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: what centralWidget? in your code I do not see any

Comment: the DrawImage is the central widget

Comment: what centralWidget? 
you talk about using a QMainWindow?

Comment: I updated my code to show everything now

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMainWindow` has a preset layout as shown below:

[image]

this layout is used to set the `toolbar`, `menubar`, `statusbar`, `dockwidget`s and the `centralwidget`. The layouts handle the position and the size of the widgets, that is why this error is generated. The solution is to set another widget as a central widget, and your `DrawImage` is the son of this new widget.

```
class Homework4(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Triangle Peg Game')
        self.setToolTip("Play the triangle peg game!")
        self.Left_button = LeftBtn(self)
        self.Right_button = RightBtn(self)
        self.Top_Button = TopBtn(self)
        self.Down_Button = DownBtn(self)

        #setting the background color
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.gray)
        #p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.gray)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        #Central Widget
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Draw = DrawImage(central_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.show()
```

Comment: @ParPro You have to be clear when you ask, do not assume things.

Answer (score 0):

The QMainWindow class you are using has a special concept of a "central" widget. It sounds like you'd rather make your main widget not the central widget, but a "Dock widget". You need to familiarize yourself with QMainWindow and the layouts QWidgets provide.